# SQL - Condição com Between

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Tenho um formulário onde o usuário pode pesquisar por um intervalo de data, até ai tudo bem. Caso ele pesquise só por uma data, como posso fazer isso de uma forma direto no sql ou até mesmo no php ?!

Alguma sugestão ?

Comment: A consulta é da mesma forma, porém você precisa por a data exata do registro.

Comment: Se você colocar a data nos sois pontos do `between`, funciona!

Comment: Faltou um exemplo da tabela no qual você esta trabalhando. E o problema não tem sentido colocar a tag phpmyadmin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De forma simples:

```
$data2 = empty($data2) ? $data1 : $data2;
$sql = "SELECT ... BETWEEN $data1 AND $data2;";
```

Se a segunda data estiver fazia recebe o valor da primeira data se não o próprio valor, você pode usar outros valores caso a segunda data for vazia, por exemplo, `"NOW()"`

Comment: No banco eu to usando o timestamp, usando dessa forma quando eu faço a busca não vem nenhum resultado, mas se eu for no banco e zera as horas dá certo

Comment: Não entendi, você salva a data e hora ou apenas a data no formato timestamp? As variáveis usadas para consulta vem em que formato (datetime, date, timestamp apenas da data, ...)? O que seria "zerar as horas"?

Comment: Deu certo aqui, muito obrigado!